# AppWidget alarmmanager not updating

Tags: android, android-widget, android-intent, alarmmanager

So, I've got a widget, I want it to update every 60 seconds. When the widget is first added to the homescreen, it runs its update function just fine. Beyond that it's supposed to start an AlarmManager, which will rerun the update method every 60 seconds. That's the part that it doesn't seem to be actually doing. Here's my code:

```
public class ClockWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE = "com.nickavv.cleanwidget.CLEANCLOCK_UPDATE";

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetIds[]) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.clocklayout);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        Log.d("log","Entered update cycle");
        //Unimportant for these purposes
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }


    private PendingIntent createClockTickIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        Log.d("onEnabled","Widget Provider enabled.  Starting timer to update widget every minute");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(), 60000, createClockTickIntent(context));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);
        Log.d("onDisabled", "Widget Provider disabled. Turning off timer");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(createClockTickIntent(context));
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        Log.d("onReceive", "Received intent " + intent);
        if (CLOCK_WIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d("onReceive", "Clock update");
            // Get the widget manager and ids for this widget provider, then
            // call the shared
            // clock update method.
            ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
            for (int appWidgetID: ids) {
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It's the product of a few tutorials I've found on the matter, and my own knowledge of Android. According to my logcats, it never gets to the Log.d("onReceive", "Clock update"); line. And yes, my Manifest is set up with the clock update intent. Thanks!

EDIT: Additional info. I put a log line in the createClockTickIntent method, and it fires off. So I guess this means that my application is running the alarmManager.setRepeating line, no idea why is isn't actually repeating.

Comment: Even though you solved your own problem by correcting a spelling mistake, thanks for posting this -- it's the most concise and simple demonstration of how to use AlarmManager to update appwidgets that I've seen anywhere!  There are so many horribly complicated solutions out there, but this cuts through all of that, with a method that is simple to understand and implement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arggghhh, it was a simple typo. The intent filter was "com.nickavv.cleanwidgets.CLEANCLOCK_UPDATE", and I had written "com.nickavv.cleanwidget.CLEANCLOCK_UPDATE"

What a pain, but hey, now I know.

So, moral of the story for anybody with a similar problem to me: Check your spelling! Check it twice, or ten times. On everything!

Comment: or just always copy/paste :-) (thanks for the question, btw! It was very helpful seeing how you did this)

Comment: For such situation it's always better to use static string variable instead of using string directly, like final static String FILTER_CLEAN_CLOCK = "com.nickavv.cleanwidgets.CLEANCLOCK_UPDATE"

Answer (score -4):

You have to make an `appwidget-provider` and set `updatePeriodMillis` on 0.6 second , then it will be update per 60 seconds.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appwidget-provider
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="146dp"
android:initialLayout="@layout/YourLayout"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0.6"
android:minHeight="144dp"/>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I know that's not correct. I have an appwidget-provider, for a start, but the updatePeriodMillis isn't allowed to be lower than 30 minutes, which is why I have to use an AlarmManager. Also, 60 milliseconds would be 0.6 seconds, not 60 seconds. Thank you very much for replying though

Comment: @Nick , You're right , But are you sure that the updatePeriodMillis isn't allowed to be lower than 30 minutes? Because I make a widget and set it on 10 minutes and it's worked.

Comment: Yeah, they've been restricted to 30 minutes since Android 1.6